# Vue3 how to get back a jsonifyied object that has been saved in the local filesystem?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, vuejs3

In vue3 SPA, I want to save an object to the local file system and then be able to upload it back to restore the object.

I could manage to save the object to file that way.

```
<ButtonExport
            :title="i18n.$t('Save the object to file ')"
         @clicked="saveToFile(object)"
         bgcolor="red"
/>



function saveToFile(model) {
    const data = JSON.stringify(model);
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain' });
    const myFile = new File([blob],'test.txt',{type: blob.type});
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = "none";
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(myFile);
    link.download =myFile.name
    // It needs to be added to the DOM so it can be clicked
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
}
```

Then to get the json text content back, I do this way

```
<input
      type="file"
      @change="onFileChanged($event)"
      accept=".txt"
     
 />
        
const uploaded_file = ref();

function   onFileChanged (event)  {
    const files = event.target.files;
    uploaded_file.value = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let text=reader.readAsText(uploaded_file)
    console.log(text);
}   

But, unfortunately I get an error message when attempting to read the file.
Uncaught TypeError: FileReader.readAsText: Argument 1 does not implement interface Blob.
onFileChanged ...

Could somebody help me fix this error?
```

Comment: I think you're not using ref correctly
`let text=reader.readAsText(uploaded_file.value)`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right. What a stupid error ! But there was more. I answer my own question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myObject = ref();

const uploaded_file = ref();
function onFileChanged(event) {
  myObject.value = null;
  const files = event.target.files;
  uploaded_file.value = files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
 
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('load event');  
    myObject.value = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    console.log(myObject);//correct, I get the object back.
  }, false);
  reader.readAsText(uploaded_file.value);

}
```